# Is there a PHP/Javascript/c#/java or ruby templating engine which supports hierarchical templates?

Tags: c#, java, php, javascript, ruby

All template engines I encountered has only one level, whereas I want to define template within template within template etc. like a russian doll.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) supports them, as well as [SiteMesh](http://www.sitemesh.org).

Answer (score 1):

Is [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) what you're looking for?

If so, stick that phrase in your searches or search for ports of Djano's template system.

From a quick search, I found a [Java port](http://www.jangod.org/), a [PHP port](http://www.h2o-template.org/), a bunch of them on the [Node.js modules page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules), a [.NET port](http://ndjango.org/index.php?title=NDjango_Home) and the [inheritance piece done in ERB for Ruby](http://matt.west.co.tt/ruby/djerb/).